# Updating Listview itemsource clears radiobutton control inside it in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

i have a simple listview in Xamarin forms. It is defined as follows.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvRadio" Grid.Row="1"
           SeparatorVisibility="None"             
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                      HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                                       HeightRequest="300">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                                                <RadioButton   BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                                                                                 Content="{Binding Description}" 
                                                                                 FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black"
                                                                                 ></RadioButton>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
```

In the code behind i am binding the listview as follows

```
            List<CommonModel> temp = new List<CommonModel>();
            CommonModel model;

            model = new CommonModel();
            model.Description = "Radio 1";
            temp.Add(model);

            model = new CommonModel();
            model.Description = "Radio 2";
            temp.Add(model);

            model = new CommonModel();
            model.Description = "Radio 3";
            temp.Add(model);

            lvRadio.ItemsSource = null;
            lvRadio.ItemsSource = temp;
```

Now when i update the ItemsSource all the radiobuttons are lost.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does "all the radiobuttons are lost" mean?

Comment: Listview does not render any radiobuttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use  **lvRadio.ItemsSource = null;lvRadio.ItemsSource = temp;**

it will cause all the values of the listview to be modified, so there will be problems.

There are two solutions:

1. Modify ListView to **ObservableCollection**,

   delete **lvRadio.ItemsSource= null;lvRadio.ItemsSource = temp;**

   so that every time the value of temp is modified, the interface will be
   automatically
   filled and the original value will not be modified.
2. RadioButton has an **IsChecked** property to record whether the
   RadioButton is selected, so you can add a property to the
   CommonModel to record whether IsChecked is selected. Then use
   **IsChecked="{Binding xxx}"**

Here is the cs page code for the first solution:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<CommonModel> temp = new ObservableCollection<CommonModel>();
    CommonModel model;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lvRadio.ItemsSource = temp;
    }
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model = new CommonModel();
        model.Description = "Radio 1";
        temp.Add(model);
        model = new CommonModel();
        model.Description = "Radio 2";
        temp.Add(model);
        model = new CommonModel();
        model.Description = "Radio 3";
        temp.Add(model);
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]